# Delete Button on Listview

Tags: android, listview

In my android app, I have a listview with an option to delete items from it
on the same screen. The delete button lies at the bottom of the list view
and there's a function written for deleting items and refreshing the list view.
This function is being called in `onClick()` of the List View.
This is where the problem lies.

In delete button's `onClick` I have first made a check for knowing which item to delete -

```
if (ListView.INVALID_POSITION != mListView.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
 //delete the selected item
}else{
 //do nothing
}
```

So whenever user touches delete button the focus from list  view is removed and we get invalid as the list view position and hence the item is not deleted.

I also tried to store the value of selected item in a constant and update it in list view's `onItemSelected()` method and then remove the condition from Delete Button's onClick
.This works but causes another problem - If the user taps into empty area then focus from list view is removed and it appears that nothing is selected, but if u press delete button and then it deletes the last selected item as it is coming from a constant.

This is the problem I am facing.
Please suggest what to do.

Comment: Are you using custom listview or simple listview?

Comment: @ankit you have to make custome adapter and you have to put delete buttnon in row file.and make the onclick item in adapter class.if u have tried any thing then post the code

Comment: @Google I am already using a custom adaptor. So please tell me is having a single delete button for all items is not right and should I change the design ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selection is useful only in keyboard mode, its turned off in touch mode so, `getSelectedItemPosition()` is not always reliable.

Read do's and don't in this [developer blog entry](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2008/12/touch-mode.html).

If you want to use a single button, Set `ListView` choice mode to Single/Mutliple, then, on button click, get the checked items and delete them, refresh `ListView` after that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement the `onitemclickListener()` and get the item id and delete the item clicked in the arrayadapter by implementing the `onclick()` for the button and next call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`